# Asterisk SIP calls ending after 2 minutes using Twilio's trunking service

Tags: networking, timeout, sip, asterisk

I have an Asterisk server hosted on DigitalOcean that is having calls drop after exactly 120 seconds using Twilio's trunking service. It is notable that directly connected softphones do not drop their calls. Port 5060 is open on the firewall as it should be.

There is an auto-attendant receiving the call and passing it to a script, but this works in full without dropping the call using a sip softphone. I e-mailed Twilio and they said that the issue could be because Asterisk is not sending a 180 Ringing, which I could understand because I'm not dialing a phone, just answering immediately.

What is really cutting off the call?

**sip.conf**

```
[twilio]
type=peer
secret=secret
username=user
host=host.domain.com
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
insecure=port,invite
fromuser=+15555555555
fromdomain=from-domain.domain.com
context=incoming
deny=0.0.0.0/0
permit=x.x.x.x/32
permit=x.x.x.x/32
permit=x.x.x.x/32
permit=x.x.x.x/32
```

**extensions.ael context**

```
+15555555555 => {
        Answer();
        EAGI(tincan.js);
        AGI(agi://127.0.0.1/saytext,"Goodbye.");
        Hangup();
}
```

**Start of call packet capture**

```
21  4.827782    (Them)  (Us)    SIP/SDP 1341    Request: INVITE sip:+15555555555@my.domain.com | 
22  4.831487    (Us)    (Them)  SIP 819 Status: 100 Trying | 
23  4.833205    (Us)    (Them)  SIP/SDP 1112    Status: 200 OK |
```

**End of call packet capture**

```
16066   124.821787  (Them)  (Us)    SIP 650 Request: BYE sip:+15555555555@x.x.x.x:5060 | 
16067   124.822736  (Us)    (Them(  SIP 700 Status: 200 OK |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was reported by Twilio as our server not sending any RTP data over an extended time, thus the connexion was timing out. The dialplan I was using ran a custom EAGI script that would record the person on the phone for an indefinite amount of time. This process was timing out on the other end.

My very hacky solution was the following:

1. Instead of using the RECORD FILE command, I used the GET OPTION command to play 10 seconds of silence, wait for the pound (#) key.
2. I used the EAGI stderr+1 fd to capture the audio to a file manually with my script.
3. I used STREAM FILE command to play back the recording to the user to confirm.

Sending the 10 seconds of silence repeatedly prevented the server from timing out. I could imagine that sending 1 second of silence would accomplish the same thing and save on bandwidth, but your mileage may vary.

My Node.js script function that replaces the WAIT FOR DIGIT or RECORD FILE functions:

```
/**
 * Loop playing silence until interrupted
 * @param done =function( timedout ) Callback when the silence has been interrupted
 * @param maxRecordTime Length of time to be able to record max. Leave blank for no timeout.
 * @param stopTime Timestamp when the recording should be stopped
 */
Index.prototype.loopSilenceUntilInterrupted = function( done, maxRecordTime, stopTime ) {
    var that = this;

    // Set the stopTime?
    if( maxRecordTime!==undefined && stopTime===undefined )
        stopTime = Date.now()+maxRecordTime;

    this.context.getOption( "silence/10", "#", 10, function( error, response ) {
        if( response.result==35 )
            done( false ); // We have been diggery
        else if( stopTime!==undefined && Date.now()>=stopTime )
            done( true ); // We have timed out!
        else
            that.loopSilenceUntilInterrupted( done, maxRecordTime, stopTime ); // Do it again
    },
    0 ); // No cooldown
};
```